# Is it possible to import key-value pairs from one INI file to another INI file

Tags: python, ini

I would like to import the key-value pairs of one INI file to another INI file so that whenever I make an update to the "parent" INI file, the changes are automatically applied to the "child" INI file as well.

Is this possible with INI files?

I understand that I could manipulate the config parser to achieve this behavior but I'm looking more for an import solution here.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can certainly have you Python code read from two (or more) INI files.

Comment: I understand that I could have Python code to read from the first INI file and write to the second INI file. But what I want to accomplish is like importing functions from other python files: from <filename> import <function_name>.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: I assume what you want is to have an import-statement inside your `ini`-file, something like:

```
import other.ini
[new values]
key = value
color = green
...
```

Basically, a `ini`-file is just a map of keys to values, something like a `dict` in the form of a text file.  They are deliberately kept rather simple.

Now, while importing another `ini`-file sounds like a really simple thing to do, it quickly comes with an entire series of problems with which other import- or inheritance mechanisms have to deal.  What happens, for instance, if two `ini`-files import each other, or what happens if `A` imports `B` and `C`, and both `B` and `C` import `D` (so called diamond problem)—do you then import `D` twice?  Hence, importing other `ini`-files is not quite as simple as one might expect, and therefore not a feature you put necessarily into a minimalistic design.

That being said, keep in mind that `ini`-file is really just a map and therefore an *inert entity*: it does not do anything at all.  In order to read an `ini`-file, you will usually need a parser like [Python's configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), which reads the textual information and creates the actual map for you.  Also, it is this parser that would have to do the importing of other files.  Hence, the question is: *is there a parser for `ini`-files that supports importing?*

I am not aware of any such parser as part of a publicly available standard package (although I assume they do exist).  You could, of course, write one yourself.

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to add imports as a special key-value pair to your `ini` file, something like `import=other.ini; another.ini` and then have your program follow these 'links' and import whatever other file(s) it is referring to.

Or you go the path of C and write a preprocessor that looks for lines that start with something like `#import other.ini` in your `ini`-file, and then merges the other `ini`-file into your text before parsing everything.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thank you for your informative response. You are correct that I am trying to have an import statement inside my INI file to import the key value pairs from another INI file. Sounds like this couldn't be done?

If not, then I will opt for manually copying all the key-value pairs over, which will require me to update both INI files separately if I ever want to update a value in the base INI file, which is not ideal.

I understand that by manipulating the config parser, this could be done, but I'm hoping for a more import kind of solution here.

Thank you!